# How to run code when item is added to list box

Tags: excel, vba, triggers, listbox

I have built a userform where a customer can pick items from a list of articles (listbox 1) to add them to their shopping chart (listbox 2) by doubleclicking the item in listbox 1.

I want code to run each time an item is added to listbox 2.

This very simple examplewhich I tried on the "Change", "Enter" and "AfterUpdate" event works probably as designed, but not as I need it to:

```
Private Sub Basket_Change()
 
        MsgBox "Change!"

End Sub
```

Nothing happens when an item is added, but when I manually select an item in listbox 2, the message appears.

I seem to recall that the change event is not triggered for textboxes when the change is not entered manually. This seems to be the same with listboxes.

I could write the line from listbox1 to a worksheet in the background at the same time I write it to listbox2, and start the code (some calculations that write values to other boxes in the same userform) from there, but I feel I should try a more direct alternative, if there is one, before I go that way.

Thanks for any hint in the right direction!

Comment: I don't see an issue with doing everything in the DoubleClick event, nor anything more 'direct'.

Comment: Ach, yes of course. I was thinking very complicated. This may seem very simple to you, but an outside view on things can be really helpful (and time-saving). Thanks!

Comment: On second thought, that will not work, but this is because I described the situation not clearly enough. What happens in the calculation is that when a new item is added to the basket, the total of all items in the basket should be recalculated.  So I think this is a case of Worksheet calculations after all.